# ISO Vegan local anesthetic for Ankle hardware removal

Tags: is-it-vegan

I am getting ready to have ankle hardware removal. Dr uses Lidocaine as a local anesthetic and I can't have that because it contains mammal ingredients. I'm allergic to all mammal products and by products. What local anesthetic is vegan?

Comment: shouldn't you be asking the anesthetist?

Comment: Lidocaine probably isn't given by an anesthetist. They should ask both here (for the sake of other readers like us) *and* the doctor. But it's highly likely the doctor has no idea. Supply chains and ingredients are often very difficult to decipher.

Comment: Cocaine is a local anesthetic that's vegan.